# Security Permission for creating an AD Distribution Group

Tags: active-directory

I would like to create an OU that only has the permission to create and manage Distribution Groups for email purposes. Is that possible and what is the permission required?

Comment: The OU does not have a permission itself. You give permissions to users do things in that OU.

Answer (score 1):

In ADUC, right-click on an OU and choose "delegate control," choose a group, and give them "modify the membership of a group."